# Error encountered when posting json data to webservice using ASIHTTPReuqest

Tags: objective-c, json, web-services, asihttprequest

i encountered this error message : 
" -[ASIFormDataRequest initWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x93b4800
2013-07-02 11:07:25.603 DesignTable[1593:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ASIFormDataRequest initWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x93b4800' "

```
-(void)sendBtnClicked:(UIButton*)sendBtn
{

for (int i = 0; i <tableArray.count; i++){

    NSMutableDictionary *tableLocation = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[tableYcoord objectAtIndex:i], @"yCoord" ,[tableXcoord objectAtIndex:i],@"xCoord", nil];
    [tableLocation setObject:[tableNameArr objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"tableName"];
    [tableLocation setObject:[tableIDArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"tableID"];
    [tableLocation setObject:[capacityArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"capacity"];


    [tableAttributes addObject:tableLocation];

    //NSMutableDictionary *tableData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:tableLocation,@"tableLocation", nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *finalDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:tableAttributes,@"table", nil];



    NSError *error;
    jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalDictionary
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];



    aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];





}

url  = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/srvs/possrv/uploadTableDesign"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"38" forKey:@"RestaurantID"];
[request setPostValue:jsonData forKey:@"json_data"];
[request startAsynchronous];

NSLog(@"%@", aStr);
sendBtn.enabled = NO;
}
```

this is my code for sending json data to my webservice.

Comment: Try using ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

Comment: @Norbert i changed it to initWithURL, but i still facing the same error :(

Comment: Download the classes available here https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree/master/Classes and replace in your project especially the ASIHTTPRequest.m and ASIHTTPRequest.h. Hope it helps.